# Repository settings in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

Where can I find the repository settings on bitbucket? It should be on the left navigation panel but I don't see it there. [What I see on the navigation panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUSyQ.png)

Comment: Then you don't have permissions to view them :)
Repository Settings are right under `Downloads`

Comment: A grayed out tab there could be so much helpful instead of just hiding it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Bitbucket Administrator, has not added you to have manage Permissions. You have to be added with admin Permission.
[image: Repository Settings]